# How can I make gradle include *.ftl files in war file

Tags: gradle

I have the following structure:

```
src/main/java/com/company/SomeJavaFile.java
src/main/java/com/company/template_file.ftl
```

When I create a build using gradle, the *.ftl files dont get included in the war file.

How can I make gradle include them in the war file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found it. You simply add the following line to your build file:

**gradle.build file (add the following line):**

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'src/main/java'
```

Got the answer from the following discussion thread:

http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Copy-non-java-files-into-the-target-directory-td1432058.html

Comment: That will also include your java-files, add an exclusion: 
sourceSets.main.resources {
    srcDir file('src/main/java')
    exclude '**/*.java'
}

Comment: Note: this solution may cause problems with your IDE's internal project structure, e.g. running `gradle idea` will result in the `src/main/java` being handled as resource directory and no longer as source directory.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution would be to put your `*.ftl` files into `src/main/resources` directory instead.

Comment: Correct answer, works for Android builds too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in src/main/webapp where, if you used them, *.jsp files would go?